# Identify duplicates in a list ignoring NA values in R

Tags: r, duplicates, nan

I have a multidimensional list similar to the following in R:

```
            Column1  Column2   Column3   Column4
```

```
  1         1          2         NA          NA
  2         2          1         1           NA
  3         1          2         1           2
  4         2          NA        NA          1
```

I would like to identify whether there are duplicates in each row, ignoring the NAs, and return the index for each row that has a duplicate.

In the example above, rows 1 and 3 have duplicates. I tried putting the information into both a matrix and data frame, and then tallying the frequency of each integer but the extra row index on the end is giving me issues.

I would appreciate any feedback. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is your actual data structure - "multidimensional list" implies something unusual and complicated, but the example you show looks like a `data.frame`, and the particular use case - all numbers, row comparisons - seems like a `matrix` would indeed be best. *"I tried putting the information into both a matrix and data frame, and then tallying the frequency of each integer but the extra row index on the end is giving me issues.*" So, is your problem that you don't know how to omit that "extra row index"? That should be pretty easy.

Comment: If you share your sample data with `dput`, it will give us a copy/pasteable dump of your data structure, with all nesting and class information included.

Comment: `(1:nrow(df))[apply(df, 1, anyDuplicated, inco=NA)>0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to do this is to use the dplyr package (and the tidyverse way of thinking).

Your question asks how to create an index, so that's what I'll give you. But be aware that the following code is removing the non-duplicates in order to do this...so if your goal is to remove non-duplicates or duplicates then you can modify the code.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  Column1 = c(1,2,1,2),
  Column2 = c(2,1,2,NA),
  Column3 = c(NA,1,1,NA),
  Column4 = c(NA,NA,2,1),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
# Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
# 1       1       2      NA      NA
# 2       2       1       1      NA
# 3       1       2       1       2
# 4       2      NA      NA       1

duplicate_rows <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(dups = anyDuplicated(na.omit(c(Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>%
  filter(dups > 0) %>%
  .$index

duplicate_rows
# [1] 2 3
```